# How to add a new action into api.php as rest api in Mediawiki?

Tags: mediawiki

I want to add a new action and link it to new model for example:

I add the new module into

```
api.php?action=mynewaction

class ApiMain extends ApiBase {
    /**
     * When no format parameter is given, this format will be used
     */
    const API_DEFAULT_FORMAT = 'xmlfm';

    /**
     * List of available modules: action name => module class
     */
    private static $Modules = array(
        'mynewaction' => 'Apimynewaction',
```

I still not able to enable the new action.

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "unknown_action",
        "info": "Unrecognized value for parameter 'action': mynewaction",
        "*": "See http://localhost/mediawiki28/api.php for API usage"
    }
}
```

If any one has information how to solve this problem

Comment: Have you looked at https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Extensions#Creating_API_modules_in_extensions ? It's not clear from your question where you got stuck.

Comment: Thank you, It work I have also to add the class into autoload.php class